# Do we need a 'livery' tag?

Tags: discussion

Ref: [Livery on rockets?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/51799/6944)

It seems unlikely that this tag will be very useful. Are there roughly similar ones already?

Answer (score 1):

Although I would not expect a huge number of questions, there is potential for maybe 6-12 questions, especially in the era of private spaceflight.

Some existing tags overlap the idea, but they are often not a good fit for the question.

So I would suggest allowing the [livery](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/livery) tag to stay.

Answer (score 0):

> Do we need a 'livery' tag?

I don't know.

> It seems unlikely that this tag will be very useful.

I'll list some questions where it *might or might not* apply. There may be a few more out there. I think there might be one more on identifying specific Saturn I or V launches based on some differences in markings, but I may be mis-remembering.

> Are there roughly similar ones already?

- I found a few but not all using the [space-art](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-art) tag.
- We don't have a "markings" or "symbol" or "logo" tag
- Per comments we do already have [insignia](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insignia), [color](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color) and [design](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) with which some items below might better be tagged instead.

---

Note, I don't know how many of these describe markings that would count as "livery".

- [Why are Soyuz rockets painted with different colors?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/5964/12102) "Progress rockets I saw have different "liveries", multicolored like this"
- [What is the purpose of the black-and-white patterns on some rockets?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/6352/12102)
- [Did the Saturn V rocket have any purely aesthetic features that didn't serve an actual function?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25314/12102)
- [Was there a rocket launched to space with Japanese manga characters painted on it?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/44173/12102)
- [What do these markings on SpaceX's ship Mr. Steven represent?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28424/12102) (it's a <s>boat</s> ship, not a spacecraft)
- [What organizations correspond to the logos on this ORBITEC Vortex engine rocket?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21586/12102)
- [Humanoid silhouette on SpaceX's Starhopper; what does it represent?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37738/12102)
- [Why does Curiosity have two images of itself on itself, or is one a QR-code?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38975/12102)
- [Saturn V Small Rectangles On S-II Stage](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41458/12102)
- [Did Wernher von Braun really have the "Saturn V painted as the V2"?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38211/12102)
- [Livery on rockets?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/51799/12102) (also mentioned in the question)

Comment: We do have an [tag:insignia] tag, but that doesn't really extend to the entire concept of livery. The [tag:color] tag has been used for questions about exterior and interior coloration of rockets before. The more general [tag:design] tag has been applied to such questions before.

Comment: This is just informational, btw. I'm not agreeing or disagreeing here.

Comment: @called2voyage Ah those should be included in the discussion so I'll add them above, thanks! with my artfully mealy-mouthed wording “I don't know”, “might or might not”, “may be”, “might be” , “may be” and again, “I don't know” I'm not sure there is much here to agree or disagree with :-)

Comment: I meant not agreeing or disagreeing with the statement in the question: "It seems unlikely that this tag will be very useful."